# Use jquery or javascript to add commas to disabled field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that I'm using to calculate some numbers, and the final 3 input fields on the form are disabled because they show the results of the calculator.

I'm using the following javascript/jquery to add commas to the user editable fields which works great but I can't seem to find a way to add commas to the "results" fields:

```
$('input.seperator').change(function(event){
  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

  var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1,").split("").reverse().join(""));

  // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
  $this.val(num2);
});

function RemoveRougeChar(convertString){

if(convertString.substring(0,1) == ","){

return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length)            

}

return convertString;
}
```

This is what I'm using the populate the fields, basically the fields show the results in dollars, so I'm trying to add a comma every 3 numbers:

```
$('#incorrect-payment').val(fieldK);
$('#correcting-payment').val(fieldL);
$('#total-cost').val(fieldM);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to use a function like this:

```
function FormatCurrency(amount, showDecimals) {

    if (showDecimals == null)
        showDecimals = true;

    var i = parseFloat(amount);
    if (isNaN(i)) { i = 0.00; }
    var minus = false;
    if (i < 0) { minus = true; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    i = parseInt((i + .005) * 100);
    i = i / 100;
    s = new String(i);

    if (showDecimals) {
    if (s.indexOf('.') < 0) { s += '.00'; }
    if (s.indexOf('.') == (s.length - 2)) { s += '0'; }
    }

    //s = minus + s;
    s = '$' + FormatCommas(s, showDecimals);
    if (minus)
        s = "(" + s + ")";
    return s;
}

function FormatCommas(amount, showDecimals) {
    if (showDecimals == null)
        showDecimals = true;


    var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
    var a = amount.split('.', 2)
    var d = a[1];
    var i = parseInt(a[0]);
    if (isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    var minus = '';
    if (i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while (n.length > 3) {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length - 3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0, n.length - 3);
    }
    if (n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);

    if (!showDecimals) {
        amount = n;
    }
    else {
    if (d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
    else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
    }
    amount = minus + amount;
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a little dense, but how can I apply that to this: `$('#incorrect-payment').val(fieldK);` Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that fieldK is a non-formatted number value. So you'd apply like this: $('#incorrect-payment').val(FormatCurrency(fieldK, true));

Comment: Something must be wrong with my code then, if I add that in I don't get any results, all of the fields clear and nothing appears in my results fields. Thanks, I'll have to keep working on this.

Comment: If you can put together a jsFiddle I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

May be you might want to trigger change event manually through javascript for your three read-only input fields. Using jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) . I am not sure but it seems like a bad idea to have a read-only input field if no user can change these values. Usually having read-only input fields is good if a user with some security can edit those and some cannot.